# How to mount Docker container volumes to different path?

Tags: docker, lxc

Container #1 runs with a volume defined for `/data`, and I'd like to use the run option `--volumes-from` to mount this volume to another container, but I'd like to change the path for the second container.

In other words `/data` from container #1 should be mounted to `/custom/data` inside container #2.

Is that possible? Is there a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's currently not possible to customize the `--volumes-from`option.
You can try [this "dirty" hack][1] though.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137544/how-to-map-volume-paths-using-dockers-volumes-from

Comment: Actually, this was a comment. @mbarthelemy would you mind putting it as an answer that can be accepted?

Comment: Does a symlink not do the trick for you? If you dont want to mutate the docker image, you can also consider using an environment variable to pass to a bootstrap script that makes the symlink, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to add custom options to `--volumes-from`.

There are two possible solutions. However, neither is perfect...

**Solution 1**

Personally, I do not like this as it only works in Linux. It will not work with Boot2Docker. [How to map volume paths using Docker's --volumes-from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137544/how-to-map-volume-paths-using-dockers-volumes-from)

**Solution 2**

The second solution is to use a sym-link. This works pretty great but there is a caveat at the end.

Run a docker container with an interactive shell and the volumes from container #1; busybox is ideal for this:

```
docker run --rm -it --volumes-from container-1-name busybox
```

where `container-1-name` is the name of container#1.

Within the shell that opens, you can create a symbolic link that points from `/custom/data` to `/data`. Assuming that the root to `/custom` already exists (use `mkdir` first if not), type:

```
ln -s /data /custom/data
```

Now you can check this link exists. You should see something like this:

```
/ # ls -l custom/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             5 Mar  4 08:09 data -> /data
```

Then you are done with this container. Exit. Now, if you create a new container than uses `--volumes-from container-1-name`, it can access the contents of `/data` via `/custom/data`.

Caveat: You should note that containers using `--volumes-from container-1-name` will have both `/data` and `/custom/data`. There is no way around that using this solution. In most situations, I imagine this is fine. However, if this no good for you, you will need to find another solution.

Comment: The symlink solution was simple and worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use `--volumes-from`?
You can use:

```
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/path1 --name container1 image1:v1.0.0
docker run -d -v DataVolume1:/path2 --name container2 image2:v1.0.0
```

or better `--mount` instead of `-v`.
You can create and then attach the container or create and attach directly the volume to the first container and then to the second (my example)