# How do you list volumes in docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container

When using docker images from registries, I often need to see the volumes created by the image's containers.

*Note: I'm using docker version 1.3.2 on Red Hat 7.*

### Example

The `postgres` official image from the Docker Registry has a volume configured for containers at `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

What's the most succinct command to show the volume at `/var/lib/postgresql/data` in a `postgres` container?

Comment: Note: that seems to have changed with docker 1.8.1: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309)

Answer (score 631, accepted):

Use `docker ps` to get the container id.

Then use that container id in the `docker inspect` command to find the mounts for that container:

```bash
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' containerid
```

Example:

terminal 1

```bash
docker run -it -v /tmp:/tmp ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

terminal 2

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ddb7b55902cc        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       distracted_banach   

$ docker inspect -f "{{ .Mounts }}" ddb7
map[/tmp:/tmp]
```

The output

```
map[/tmp:/tmp]
```

is, apparently, due to the use of the *Go* language to implement the docker command tools.

The `docker inspect` command without the `-f format` is quite verbose.  Since it is JSON you could pipe it to python or nodejs and extract whatever you needed.

```
paul@home:~$ docker inspect ddb7
[{
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "Args": [],
    "Config": {
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Cpuset": "",
        "Domainname": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ],
        "ExposedPorts": null,
        "Hostname": "ddb7b55902cc",
        "Image": "ubuntu:14.04",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "PortSpecs": null,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Tty": true,
        "User": "",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": ""
    },
    "Created": "2015-05-08T22:41:44.74862921Z",
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/tmp:/tmp"
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Links": null,
        "LxcConf": [],
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "PidMode": "",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
            "Name": ""
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null
    },
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ddb7b55902cc328612d794570fe9a936d96a9644411e89c4ea116a5fef4c311a/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ddb7b55902cc328612d794570fe9a936d96a9644411e89c4ea116a5fef4c311a/hosts",
    "Id": "ddb7b55902cc328612d794570fe9a936d96a9644411e89c4ea116a5fef4c311a",
    "Image": "ed5a78b7b42bde1e3e4c2996e02da778882dca78f8919cbd0deb6694803edec3",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "Name": "/distracted_banach",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "docker0",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "fe80::42:acff:fe11:4",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {}
    },
    "Path": "/bin/bash",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ddb7b55902cc328612d794570fe9a936d96a9644411e89c4ea116a5fef4c311a/resolv.conf",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "State": {
        "Error": "",
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Pid": 6115,
        "Restarting": false,
        "Running": true,
        "StartedAt": "2015-05-08T22:41:45.367432585Z"
    },
    "Volumes": {
        "/tmp": "/tmp"
    },
    "VolumesRW": {
        "/tmp": true
    }
}
]
```

`docker history <image name>` will show the layers baked into an image.  Unfortunately, `docker history` seems hobbled by its formatting and lack of options to choose what is displayed.

You can choose terse and verbose formats, via the --no-trunc flag.

```
$ docker history drpaulbrewer/spark-worker
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE
438ff4e1753a        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/sh -c /spark/my-s   0 B
6b664e299724        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:09da603c5f0dca7cc6   296 B
f6ae126ae124        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaf   0 B
70bcb3ffaec9        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 2222/tcp 4040/tcp 60   0 B
1332ac203849        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get --yes up   1.481 GB
8e6f1e0bb1b0        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/www.g   1.975 kB
b3d242776b1f        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /spark/spark-1.3.1    0 B
ac0d6cc5aa3f        2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:b6549e3d28e2d149c0   25.89 MB
6ee404a44b3f        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /spark                0 B
c167faff18cf        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c adduser --disabled-password --home   335.1 kB
f55d468318a4        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaf   0 B
19c8c047d0fe        8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/bash]               0 B
c44d976a473f        8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.879 kB
14dbf1d35e28        8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/polic   701 B
afa7a164a0d2        8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:57f97478006b988c0c   131.5 MB
511136ea3c5a        23 months ago                                                       0 B
```

Here's a verbose example.

```
$ docker history --no-trunc=true drpaulbrewer/spark-worker
IMAGE                                                              CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        SIZE
438ff4e1753a60779f389a3de593d41f7d24a61da6e1df76dded74a688febd64   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/sh -c /spark/my-spark-worker.sh]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0 B
6b664e29972481b8d6d47f98167f110609d9599f48001c3ca11c22364196c98a   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:09da603c5f0dca7cc60f1911caf30c3c70df5e4783f7eb10468e70df66e2109f in /spark/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            296 B
f6ae126ae124ca211c04a1257510930b37ea78425e31a273ea0b1495fa176c57   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaftc.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0 B
70bcb3ffaec97a0d14e93b170ed70cc7d68c3c9dfb0222c1d360a300d6e05255   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 2222/tcp 4040/tcp 6066/tcp 7077/tcp 7777/tcp 8080/tcp 8081/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0 B
1332ac20384947fe1f15107213b675e5be36a68d72f0e81153d6d5a21acf35af   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get --yes upgrade     && apt-get --yes install sed nano curl wget openjdk-8-jdk scala     && echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64" >>/etc/environment     && export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"     && ./build/mvn -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package     && chown -R spark:spark /spark     && mkdir /var/run/sshd   1.481 GB
8e6f1e0bb1b0b9286947d3a4b443cc8099b00f9670aab1d58654051e06f62e51   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/www.gtlib.gatech.edu\/pub/' /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/sources.list && mv /tmp/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       1.975 kB
b3d242776b1f1f1ae5685471d06a91a68f92845ef6fc6445d831835cd55e5d0b   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /spark/spark-1.3.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0 B
ac0d6cc5aa3fdc3b65fc0173f6775af283c3c395c8dae945cf23940435f2785d   2 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:b6549e3d28e2d149c0bc84f69eb0beab16f62780fc4889bcc64cfc9ce9f762d6 in /spark/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            25.89 MB
6ee404a44b3fdd3ef3318dc10f3d002f1995eea238c78f4eeb9733d00bb29404   5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /spark                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0 B
c167faff18cfecedef30343ef1cb54aca45f4ef0478a3f6296746683f69d601b   5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c adduser --disabled-password --home /spark spark                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        335.1 kB
f55d468318a4778733160d377c5d350dc8f593683009699c2af85244471b15a3   5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER drpaulbrewer@eaftc.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0 B
19c8c047d0fe2de7239120f2b5c1a20bbbcb4d3eb9cbf0efa59ab27ab047377a   8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD [/bin/bash]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0 B
c44d976a473f143937ef91449c73f2cabd109b540f6edf54facb9bc2b4fff136   8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1.879 kB
14dbf1d35e2849a00c6c2628055030fa84b4fb55eaadbe0ecad8b82df65cc0db   8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               && echo 'exit 101' >> /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d    && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d                        && dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl    && cp -a /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d /sbin/initctl    && sed -i 's/^exit.*/exit 0/' /sbin/initctl                        && echo 'force-unsafe-io' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker-apt-speedup                        && echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean    && echo 'APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean    && echo 'Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean                        && echo 'Acquire::Languages "none";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-no-languages                        && echo 'Acquire::GzipIndexes "true"; Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: "gz";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes   701 B
afa7a164a0d215dbf45cd1aadad2a4d12b8e33fc890064568cc2ea6d42ef9b3c   8 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:57f97478006b988c0c68e5bf82684372e427fd45f21cd7baf5d974d2cfb29e65 in /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  131.5 MB
511136ea3c5a64f264b78b5433614aec563103b4d4702f3ba7d4d2698e22c158   23 months ago                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0 B
```

Comment: @CivFan You might also ask another question about Go format strings to get the output into a string format you can use....  that would be a Go question not a docker question.

Comment: For flexibility the are usually no included volumes but instead the -v option to docker run is used to attach at runtime.  I seem to recall a dockerfile option but never have seen that used. Recommend asking a new question about any of this as beyond the scope of the current one. Maybe someone else can help, at a new question will be most effective to attract new answers.

Comment: I culled this question down to just containers, and [asked a new question for images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31999646/2125392).

Comment: It's no longer Volumes but Mounts.

Comment: This website has a pretty good explanation as well: https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277/10

Comment: In Windows, you need to use double quotation.
docker inspect -f "{{ .Mounts }}" containerid

Comment: It's also possible to use container's name instead of id in `docker inspect`, which is often more convenient.

Answer (score 138):

With docker 1.10, you now have new commands for data-volume containers.
(for regular containers, see the next section, for docker 1.8+):

- [`docker volume ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/)
- [`docker volume inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/)

---

With docker 1.8.1 (August 2015), a `docker inspect -f '{{ .Volumes }}' containerid` would be **empty!**

You now need to check **`Mounts`**, which is a list of mounted paths like:

```
   "Mounts": [
       {
           "Name": "7ced22ebb63b78823f71cf33f9a7e1915abe4595fcd4f067084f7c4e8cc1afa2",
           "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/7ced22ebb63b78823f71cf33f9a7e1915abe4595fcd4f067084f7c4e8cc1afa2/_data",
           "Destination": "/home/git/repositories",
           "Driver": "local",
           "Mode": "",
           "RW": true
       }
   ],
```

If you want the path of the *first* mount (for instance), that would be (using index 0):

```
docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 0).Source }}' containerid
```

As [Mike Mitterer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504184/mike-mitterer) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers/31997267#comment64041575_31997267):

> Pretty print the whole thing:

```
 docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' containerid | python -m json.tool
```

Or, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers/31997267?noredirect=1#comment75949932_31997267) by [Mitja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1651498/mitja), use the [`jq` command](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

```
docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' containerid | jq
```

Comment: Pretty print the whole thing: docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' containerid | python -m json.tool

Comment: @MikeMitterer Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: If you want pretty-print with pretty colors, you could install the `jq` package under ubuntu, and then just pipe to it: `docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' containerid | jq`

Comment: @Mitja Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 86):

I actually googled this, and found my own answer :) My memory these days... And for those that dont know about it [commandlinefu](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/24283/list-docker-volumes-by-container) is a nice place to find and publish these kinda snippets.

List docker volumes by container.

```sh
docker ps -a --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -I {} docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}{{ printf "\n" }}{{ range .Mounts }}{{ printf "\n\t" }}{{ .Type }} {{ if eq .Type "bind" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ .Name }} => {{ .Destination }}{{ end }}{{ printf "\n" }}' {}
```

Example output.

```
root@jac007-truserv-jhb1-001 ~/gitlab $ docker ps -a --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -I {} docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}{{ printf "\n" }}{{ range .Mounts }}{{ printf "\n\t" }}{{ .Type }} {{ if eq .Type "bind" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ .Name }} => {{ .Destination }}{{ end }}{{ printf "\n" }}' {}
/gitlab_server_1

    volume gitlab-data => /var/opt/gitlab
    volume gitlab-config => /etc/gitlab
    volume gitlab-logs => /var/log/gitlab

/gitlab_runner_1

    bind /var/run/docker.sock => /var/run/docker.sock
    volume gitlab-runner-config => /etc/gitlab-runner
    volume 35b5ea874432f55a26c769e1cdb1ee3f06f78759e6f302e3c4b4aa40f3a495aa => /home/gitlab-runner
```

Comment: This one does what i need.

Comment: Splendid command, I'll use an alias for this!

Comment: Let's admit, this is the one we needed.

Answer (score 25):

Show names and mount point destinations of volumes used by a container:

```
docker container inspect \
 -f '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Name }}:{{ .Destination }} {{ end }}' \
 CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME
```

*This is compatible with Docker 1.13.*

Answer (score 14):

From Docker Documentation  [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#formatting)

```
.Mounts Names of the volumes mounted in this container.
```

`docker ps -a --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Mounts}}"`

should work

Answer (score 13):

You can get information about which volumes were specifically baked into the container by inspecting the container and looking in the JSON output and comparing a couple of the fields. When you run `docker inspect myContainer`, the `Volumes` and `VolumesRW` fields give you information about **ALL** of the volumes mounted inside a container, including volumes mounted in both the Dockerfile with the `VOLUME` directive, and on the command line with the `docker run -v` command. However, you can isolate which volumes were mounted in the container using the `docker run -v` command by checking for the `HostConfig.Binds` field in the `docker inspect` JSON output. To clarify, this `HostConfig.Binds` field tells you which volumes were mounted specifically in your `docker run` command with the `-v` option. So if you cross-reference this field with the `Volumes` field, you will be able to determine which volumes were baked into the container using `VOLUME` directives in the Dockerfile.

A grep could accomplish this like:

```
$ docker inspect myContainer | grep -C2 Binds
...
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/var/docker/docker-registry/config:/registry"
    ],
```

And...

```
$ docker inspect myContainer | grep -C3 -e "Volumes\":"
...
"Volumes": {
    "/data": "/var/lib/docker...",
    "/config": "/var/lib/docker...",
    "/registry": "/var/docker/docker-registry/config"
```

And in my example, you can see I've mounted `/var/docker/docker-registry/config` into the container as `/registry` using the `-v` option in my `docker run` command, and I've mounted the `/data` and `/config` volumes using the `VOLUME` directive in my Dockerfile. The container **does not** need to be running to get this information, but it needs to have been run at least one time in order to populate the `HostConfig` JSON output of your `docker inspect` command.

Comment: What is  `HostConfig.Binds` and how is it different from `.Volumes` seen in the answer from @Paul?

Comment: I've just spent the last hour looking through the [remote API docs](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.18/) and the [source](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/volumes/repository.go) to discover the difference, and from what I can tell, `.Volumes` lists "object mapping mountpoint paths (strings) inside the container to empty objects", and `HostConfig.Binds` describes actual bind-mounted volumes in the container. It seems to me then that `HostConfig.Binds` is what you want to read, versus `.Volumes`, though I would love to hear better reasoning.

Comment: I have asked in `#docker` on Freenode (the main channel for docker), and if I hear something back, I'll definitely update here with more information. It's a very good question you've asked here about the difference. Thanks!

Comment: @CivFan I was sort of wrong. In order to see which volumes have been baked into the image, you need to use BOTH the Volumes and HostConfig.Binds fields in the JSON output of docker inspect. I have corrected myself in this answer, which now more or less correctly answers your question versus what I had before. Good luck! :)

Comment: Have you noticed `HostConfig.Binds` is only populated when the volume's host path is specified? For example, `docker run -d -v /docker-test:/docker-test postgres` vs. `docker run -d -v /docker-test postgres`. It seems docker handles these two volume cases quite differently for some reason.

Comment: Yes, that's because in the first case, you are specifying a data directory volume, and in the second, you are merely specifying a volume. This took me some time to wrap my head around. Volumes are persistent data storage units. If you specify a volume without mounting a directory on the host, docker is merely going to persist the data written to the volume directory (even if it only exists inside the container, and is not bind-mounted to a host directory). This is also the case with Dockerfile volumes. The data inside them is stored (and not deleted!) when the container dies.

Answer (score 13):

if you want to list all the containers name with the relevant volumes that attached to each container you can try this:

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker container inspect -f '{{ .Name }} {{ .HostConfig.Binds }}'
```

example output:

> /opt_rundeck_1 [/opt/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
>   /var/lib/rundeck/var/storage:/var/lib/rundeck/var/storage:rw
>   /opt/var/rundeck/.ssh:/var/lib/rundeck/.ssh:rw
>   /opt/etc/rundeck:/etc/rundeck:rw /var/log/rundeck:/var/log/rundeck:rw
>   /opt/rundeck-plugins:/opt/rundeck-plugins:rw
>   /opt/var/rundeck:/var/rundeck:rw]

/opt_rundeck_1 - container name

[..] - volumes attached to the conatiner

Comment: While this technically is an answer to the question, it lacks explanation.  Please edit your comment so that you explain what the parameters are doing and why the question asker would want to use them to solve the problem posed in his/her question.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one line command to get the volume information for running containers:

```
for contId in `docker ps -q`; do echo "Container Name: "   `docker ps -f "id=$contId" | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES`; echo "Container Volume: " `docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Volumes}}' $contId`; docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' $contId  | jq '.[]';   printf "\n"; done
```

Output is:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/lib# for contId in `docker ps -q`; do echo "Container Name: "   `docker ps -f "id=$contId" | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES`; echo "Container Volume: " `docker inspect -f '{{.Config.Volumes}}' $contId`; docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' $contId  | jq '.[]';   printf "\n"; done

Container Name:  freeradius
Container Volume:  map[]

Container Name:  postgresql
Container Volume:  map[/run/postgresql:{} /var/lib/postgresql:{}]
{
  "Propagation": "",
  "RW": true,
  "Mode": "",
  "Driver": "local",
  "Destination": "/run/postgresql",
  "Source":     "/var/lib/docker/volumes/83653a53315c693f0f31629f4680c56dfbf861c7ca7c5119e695f6f80ec29567/_data",
  "Name": "83653a53315c693f0f31629f4680c56dfbf861c7ca7c5119e695f6f80ec29567"
}
{
  "Propagation": "rprivate",
  "RW": true,
  "Mode": "",
  "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql",
  "Source": "/srv/docker/postgresql"
}

Container Name:  rabbitmq
Container Volume:  map[]
```

Docker version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:44:32 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 21:44:32 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 9):

We can do it without the -f Go template syntax:

```
docker inspect <CONTAINER_ID> | jq .[].Mounts
```

The first jq operation `jq .[]` strips the object `{}` wrapper.

The second jq operation will return all the Mount items.

Comment: Or `docker inspect <ContainerID> | jq --raw-output .[].Mounts`

Comment: I get `null`. Why?

Answer (score 8):

For Docker 1.8, I use:

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{ .Config.Volumes }}" 957d2dd1d4e8
map[/xmount/dvol.01:{}]
$
```

Answer (score 7):

To print the Mounts using `Type:Source:Destination` format:

```
docker container inspect \
    -f '{{range .Mounts}}{{.Type}}:{{.Source}}:{{.Destination}}{{println}}{{ end }}' \
    <containerId>
```

To print only the `Source` of Mounts with `Type="volume"`:

```
docker container inspect \
    -f '{{range .Mounts}}{{ if eq .Type "volume" }}{{println .Source }}{{ end }}{{end}}' \
    <containerId>
```

Answer (score 5):

Useful variation for docker-compose users:

```
docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker container inspect  \
   -f '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Name }}:{{ .Destination }} {{ end }}'
```

This will very neatly output parseable volume info. Example from my wordpress docker-compose:

```
ubuntu@core $ docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker container inspect  -f '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Name }}:{{ .Destination }} {{ end }}' 
core_wpdb:/var/lib/mysql 
core_wpcode:/code core_wphtml:/var/www/html
```

The output contains one line for each container, listing the volumes (and mount points) used. Alter the *{{ .Name }}:{{ .Destination }}* portion to output the info you would like.

If you just want a simple list of volumes, one per line

```
$ docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker container inspect  \
   -f '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Name }} {{ end }}' \
   | xargs -n 1 echo
core_wpdb
core_wpcode
core_wphtml
```

Great to generate a list of volumes to backup. I use this technique along with [Blacklabelops Volumerize](https://github.com/blacklabelops/volumerize) to backup all volumes used by all containers within a docker-compose. The docs for Volumerize don't call it out, but you don't need to use it in a persistent container or to use the built-in facilities for starting and stopping services. I prefer to leave critical operations such as backup and service control to the actual user (outside docker). My backups are triggered by the actual (non-docker) user account, and use docker-compose stop to stop services, backup all volumes in use, and finally docker-compose start to restart.

Answer (score 5):

Using single quotes on docker version >= 1.8

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' containerid
```

leads to the following error -

```
Template parsing error: template: :1: unclosed action
```

Use double quotes instead -

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .Mounts }}" <contained-id>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
docker inspect -f '{{ json .Mounts }}' containerid | jq '.[]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version to find mount points of a docker compose. 
In use this to backup the volumes.

```
 # for Id in $(docker-compose -f ~/ida/ida.yml ps -q); do docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 0).Source }}' $Id; done
/data/volumes/ida_odoo-db-data/_data
/data/volumes/ida_odoo-web-data/_data
```

This is a combination of previous solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pwsh (powershell core), you can try

```
(docker ps --format='{{json .}}' |  ConvertFrom-Json).Mounts
```

also you can see both container name and Mounts as below

```
docker ps --format='{{json .}}' |  ConvertFrom-Json | select Names,Mounts
```

As the output is converted as json ,you can get any properties it has.

Answer (score 1):

Print all containers with their Docker volumes:

```bash
docker container inspect $(docker container ls -q) \
  -f '{{$container := .Name}}{{range .Mounts}}{{if eq .Type "volume"}}{{$container}} {{.Name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}' \
  | grep -v '^$'
```