# ssh into boot2docker - can you see -v folders from within boot2docker vm

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Can you do the following?
ssh into boot2docker - and see -v folders from within boot2docker vm

I am looking for this as I need to have a process(web pack-dev-server) to react on file changed events. This do not work with simple -h folders in docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh into boot2docker is the usual way to work with that tool: you ssh to the boot2docker vm.

Once the ssh session is opened, you [can inspect containers to list volumes for each one](http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html).

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }},{{ range $key, $value := .Volumes }}{{ $key }},{{ $value }}##~#{{ end }}' <container_id>
```

Note: since docker 1.8, inspect the volumes now uses `.Mounts`.
See "[How do you list volumes in docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309)".