# Is the data in unbound docker container volumes committed to the image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

The `postgres` image, for example, has a volume baked in at `/var/lib/postgresl/data`, but it isn't bound to a particular host path. I'm wondering if the database work done in this container is wholly encapsulated by committing the container to an image, or if I need to separately pass along the contents of the unbound volume.

### Example in commands

Create container `vtest` based on `postgres` image:

```
$ docker run -d --name vtest postgres
```

The container has a volume at `/var/lib/postgresql/data` [that is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134316/2125392) to a host path:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Volumes }}' vtest
map[/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/bc39da05ff1cd044d7a17bba61381e854a948fb70cf39f897247f5ada66ad906]
$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.Binds }}' vtest
<no value>
```

Create a database and add some records in the `vtest` container. Then, commit the changes to an image to be able to share with others:

```
$ docker commit -p vtest postgres:vtest
```

Will the changes made in the `vtest` container's `/var/lib/postgresql/data` persist in this new `postgres:vtest` image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volumes mounted in the container are not committed to the image, not matter it is mounted to a particular folder of your host or it's mounted to a folder in `/var/lib/docker`. In fact, as you show in your message, the volume is mounted to `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/bc39da05ff1cd044d7a17bba61381e854a948fb70cf39f897247f5ada66ad906` in host machine. You can browse that folder as root user.

If you want to save the data in a volume you would need to use other approach different to committing. One of the more used ones is using data containers (which will create also a folder in `/var/lib/container/...` with your data), and then saving that volume using a new container an a packing tool like `tar`. Check [Docker documentation related to this topic](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) for further details.

Comment: Seems odd that you have to go outside docker to share the actual volume data, so I figured I was missing something. I guess not! Thanks for the `tar` workflow tip.