# How do you find volumes configured into the docker *image* itself?

Tags: docker

[This question asks about listing volumes in containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30133664/2125392)

But what I'm looking for here is, how do you find volumes configured into an **image** itself, without creating a container first?

The idea is, I want to know what an image might do with volumes mapped to the host file system, before allowing a container to run from that image.

The official `postgres` image is a good example. When you start a container of this image, it automatically creates a volume at `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. Is there a way to figure that out before starting a container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  You can use the `docker inspect` command on the image.  For example:

```
$ docker inspect postgres
[...]
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
        },
[...]
```

If you want to avoid all the other output, you can use:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{.ContainerConfig.Volumes}}' postgres
map[/var/lib/postgresql/data:{}]
```

Comment: If you want to use the output in scripts, its possible to output an array with a little more work (sorry, dont know how to do formatting in comments): 

`docker inspect --format='{{range $a, $b := .Config.Volumes }}{{ printf "\"%s\" " $a }}{{end}}' postgres`

Output: `"/var/lib/postgresql/data" `