# Determine creator of Docker volume?

Tags: docker

I have a lot of volumes in Docker that don't have an owner anymore. I'm really curious who keeps creating them, but I cannot figure it out. The volumes are empty inside, so I cannot determine it from their content.

And when I run `docker volume inspect` I get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-05-17T02:56:30+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/storage/docker/volumes/4db244d1741392b730eb4de50ce492ba2b19973aaef51bc5eaa41b4739c246e9/_data",
        "Name": "4db244d1741392b730eb4de50ce492ba2b19973aaef51bc5eaa41b4739c246e9",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

It seems really weird to me that Docker doesn't even record the name of the creator, so am I missing something? How do I track down the previous owner?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with enough source code to demonstrate this issue?  For example, I could easily see a Dockerfile with an unnecessary `VOLUME` directive causing this.

Comment: @DavidMaze To be honest this isnt really a programming question. I just have 15 containers running that I downloaded and one of them is creating these ghost volumes. So there is not any sourcecode involved.

Comment: A volume doesn't have a "creator" or an "owner". Volumes can be created directly, without involving any containers. You can see what volumes are attached to *running* containers by using `docker inspect`, but there's nothing like a history of containers to which a volume was previously attached.

Comment: @larsks It would be really helpful if this "attachment history" was kept somewhere. Do you have any other suggestions how to debug this?

Comment: Those volumes are created by images that include a `VOLUME` declaration in their Dockerfile. You can `docker image inspect` to see if an image will create any volumes ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001068/147356)).