# Docker volumes for persistent data - is it enough to pass container path only?

Tags: docker

As I understand docker volumes allow to specify directory/file in docker container that will be shared/stored on docker host. For example postgres Dockerfile contains following line

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

So it means that `/var/lib/postgresql/data` will be actually "stored" on host and I will have access to that file(s) from a host system. For example when I inspect pg container:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "4fc1fe18d93fd2090f63619edc5d6244e9821805a2e070a0235d9305b2dfe80f",
            "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/4fc1fe18d93fd2090f63619edc5d6244e9821805a2e070a0235d9305b2dfe80f/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
```

This means that I can find volume on host under `Source` path. I was wondering what means `4fc1fe18d93fd2090f63619edc5d6244e9821805a2e070a0235d9305b2dfe80f` in the `Source` path. I can't find neither container nor image with such id on my docker host.

One thing I can't understand is that it seems that when I remove container and recreate it, then `Source` path is different, and in fact no data persist...

So it seems that for data persistance I have to add volume with both host and container paths to force it to store data always under same path - is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following "[How do you list volumes in docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309)", I have written a script ([`updateDataContainerPath`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/docker1.9/updateDataContainerPath)) which:

- either records that path in a file (named after the container)
- or, if that file already exist, will:

  - delete Mount.Source folder (which is empty)
  - move the path recorded in the file to Mount.Source path
  - record Mount.Source path in that file

That way, I can delete (`docker rm`, without the `-v` option, obviously) a container and recreate it, while keeping the data put in that volume.

You can see that script used in [`gitolite/run`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1df5b9acb67ddcd357a38c823e797835ea3414db/gitolite/run#L21-L24) for instance.

Comment: That's cool - but I can also just specify fixed host path to achieve the same right?

Comment: @user606521 I don't know, I preferred not to tweak with that generated path, and always keep the one provided by a `docker run` or `docker create`.

Comment: @user606521 did you try the other option (specify a fixed host path)?

Comment: @user606521 how did you change that path in the container?

Comment: I've just created container with following volume `/var/lib/api/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` - it's `<host_path>:<container_path>` - and now all files from `<container_path>` are visible on host at `<host_path>`.

Comment: @user606521 OK. You are using a data volume (https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes). My script is for using (and preserving) a data volume container (https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Answer (score 1):

> So it seems that for data persistance I have to add volume with both
>   host and container paths to force it to store data always under same
>   path - is this correct?

Correct. That is called "mounting a host directory as a data volume". Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).

But it can be achieved with something like:

```
docker run -v /path/to/host/directory:/path/inside/the/container image
```

Other option is using a "data volume container". In this way, you bind your container(s) into a data volume container. You can re create your container(s), and as long as you don't remove the data volume container, data will be persisted. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).