# Docker restore volume of removed container?

Tags: docker, backup, containers, volume, restore

At the moment I am trying to understand some scenarios concerning data persistence.

The Data Volume Container Pattern sounds great, and there are ways to backup the attached volumes. But what if I have no current backup the DataVolumeContainer gets removed (rather than only stopped)?

From what I understand the volume is physically still present on my host system, but I can't attach it to a new container (since there's no referencing container left).

Is there a possibility to restore that volume (e.g. mount it to a new container) by referencing its volume file or the volume name? (assuming that I named the volume)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I can't attach it to a new container (since there's no referencing container left).
>   Is there a possibility to restore that volume (e.g. mount it to a new container) by referencing its volume file or the volume name (assuming that I named the volume)?

Yes there is: if you can find your old volume path, you can, as I mentioned in "[Docker mount dangling volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33931071/6309)", restore its content in a *new* (and empty) data volume container by replacing its [mounting path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309) content with the one found in the old path.

I prefer [saving that path whenever I create a new data volume container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32113001/6309).

Comment: Thank you! So basically when i know which volume I want to attach to a new container I can simply use the path to the volume (on the host system) as the host-dir in '-v <host-dir>:<container-dir>'?
Awesome! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @Ciprian I was not talking about volumes, but data volume containers, which will store data in /var/lib/docker/volumes/xxx.

Comment: Yeah but you attached the volume of the old Data Volume Container to a new container by modifying its mounting path, right?

Comment: @Ciprian I keep the mounting path of the new one, but put in it the content of the old one (actually, I remove the new mounting path, and rename the old one with the new mounting path: https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/65126dcaf418d8cd2c76d969cf5912ec1b671cdd/updateDataContainerPath#L36-L38)

Comment: You mean 'replace the old one with the new one', right? Either i don't get it :(

Comment: @Ciprian I mean retrieve the content of the old one, and put it in the new data volume container (I am talking about what is stored in /var/lib/docker/volumes)

Comment: Ahh okay now I get it! So simple! :p Thank you! I'm sure that I'll use your script! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear from your text if you have removed the volume with the container - then its gone - otherwise and by default you can find "raw" docker volumes here: `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. Check the docs for `docker rm -v`.

Normally you would create a volume by `docker run ... -v hostpath:containerpath ...` and then you have your data always at `hostpath` available, no matter if you remove your container or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) But my question pointed especially to data persistence when dealing with volumes. I was assuming the 'rm' command to be used without the '-v' flag, should have clarified that, sry!