# database and collections created in docker container cant be found in committed docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using and existing mongodb image to create a docker container. Then I create some databases and collections in that container. However, when I create and image from that container, mongodb does not show my databases and collections.

I guess its something to do with data volumes not copied over to image. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving container ([`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)) *with* volumes is for now a [closed (unresolved) issue (6999)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6999).
See also [issue 7583](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7583), which points to [PR 13987](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13987)

> Update the man page for 'docker commit' to make explicit the fact that
>   'commit' does not save data in volumes.

You would need to save your `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<right_volume>` yourself in order to restore its content in the new volume created by a mongodb image.
Its [Dockerfile creates two of them](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/8bb661bb5d8815929380bd577c86b3860b9aeb03/3.3/Dockerfile#L49).

```
VOLUME /data/db /data/configdb
```

I did in the past [restored the content of deleted volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32113001/6309).
I now less need that with [docker volume commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) (but those volumes still cannot be committed as an image).