# Docker volumes doesn't exist for data container in 1.9.1

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

Docker toolbox 1.9.1 on Windows 7 platform

The data container I created doesn't have volumes when I use `docker inspect` command.

```
$ sudo mkdir /abc
$ docker run -d --name data -v /abc:/hostabc busybox true
$ docker inspect --format "{{ .Config.Volumes }}" data
map[]
```

I also tried this in 1.7.1, it shows like below

```
$ docker inspect --format "{{ .Volumes }}" data   # in 1.7.1 it is Volumes directly
map[/hostabc:/abc]
```

Anything I did wrong to create the data container ?

Or there are other place to check the `volumes` in data container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
docker inspect -f '{{ (index .Mounts 0).Source }}' containerid
```

If you have multiple sharing, then simple use `range` like below

```
docker inspect -f '{{range $k := .Mounts}}{{println $k.Source }}{{end}}' containerid
```

[As I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997267/6309), that changed since docker 1.8

Note: the [PR 45](https://github.com/SvenDowideit/dockerfiles/pull/45#event-783810589) raised by the OP is [now merged](https://github.com/SvenDowideit/dockerfiles/commit/64b85baa71c02db758a5310f34fa9fdfef53d751) with directives like:

```
version=`$docker -v 2>&1 | awk -F'[ .]' '{printf "%2.f%02.f%02.f",$3,$4,$5}'`

# echo $version

if [ $version -gt 10800 ]; then
    echo "docker version 1.8+"
    volumes=`$docker inspect --format='{{range $k := .Mounts}}{{println $k.Destination}}{{end}}' "$container" |  grep -v -E "^$"`
else
    echo "docker version <1.8"
    volumes=`$docker inspect --format='{{range $k,$v := .Volumes}}{{println $k}}{{end}}' "$container" |  grep -v -E "^$"`
fi
```

Comment: terrific, got answer in  1 minute, I will check with `SvenDowideit/samba`  https://github.com/SvenDowideit/dockerfiles/issues/38

Comment: @LarryCai Great! Let us know if it is working for you and for that issue.

Comment: @LarryCai PR has been merged! I have edited the answer.