# Orphaned subvolumes, owned by nobody, can't do anything with them

Tags: docker, debian, btrfs, crostini

I'm running Debian Buster inside of Crostini on a Pixelbook, and am using Docker.  I'd backed-up my Linux container, performed a power wash on the Chromebook, then restored the Linux container.

That's when I started getting permission-denied issues when building containers, during the `mkdir` calls in my Dockerfile.

So I did the typical troubleshooting:

- uninstall/reinstall docker
- uninstall docker and run `rm -rf /var/lib/docker`
- kill all processes that **might** be using those subvolmes
- check `mount` for active mounts
- check `/etc/fstab` (which is empty?) for mounts
- check `/etc/mtab` (is this new?) for mounts
- reinstall docker and run `docker system prune` (which also didn't touch those directories)
- even tried running `btrfs subvolume delete XXXXXX`

...all of which squawk at me due to a lack of permissions... this is even when I `sudo su root` to run the comands.

I'm a complete newbie to both Docker and *definitely* to BTRFS... so I'm completely stumped now.

I'm able to build containers again... since it's building them into NEW subvolumes now... but now it's personal... I want the following subvolumes gone!

Here they are (all inside of `/var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes`):

```
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 f96f6fbdbfd84db115c253880a0e8919b63d758d4a3f9e2645bcf959657f6c45-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 f547c01038e1479c65383ee4baba4f9212c2ca42ab9536931b1df9d8149d004f-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 efff78d70c412ad613d88e58ae0a84c058d1ccce63a588f2da8612cda2099ecc
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 e1b8aacd80a48e400052fb921cc52567a75ae210aa005519671bbf3cc1e7d3e5-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 c928040adbd4fe7ec8e71643d66c7a036436fcf52318573038153bf2d73e000e-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 bc0a723bece1df18eaf4fbc2deb108909546e2088ed4cff5c29d473881061bde
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 b52f2bf1a1404a773f6ed7bdfe1cfabb1c241e74ce846da65afbdce18b021502-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 aacc82c84f1aee572a20325d5ea3ff6ccd0604dfeecf34efc6af952d62926012-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 a5a6cd588f4995f5e8517d31bce652235bfc920ba694cc681eb5dfe4e1c24192-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 9cc9807d3c3d036f38086f52ceb2d9ebc87a14a4e3f0ba41bb4e1d89f965bf99-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 9aef1d128a4608916c01c44accc883a6069a4b8131e35568337fc5b5b4c4998e
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 8de3efc8c709f46a46362e60fcc4d948cbe543f4f1a1615ccfb21d83decb7e3e
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 815d91c859262e5e556191a03438761d97bd21556cdd3b4d75d2fbdfcbb4082c-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 7c27d56096add6bb0352dc4d8d8d9c0613d79fdf370bed04c2dfe90e90215569-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 72fb7e0f7732f59c45b7872140dc64d59aaa1e719266d3e299398d7a8040f57c
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 6e284d02177f0a6fa6aea122086a3934c0e6b8498d862df718f333bf50fd77db
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 617f090a6c681e1345fb32af0aa76d410c7e3b5353bceda11c266efaafaca09e
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 5312ab94752a8ad47a222e98c7633c0d3ca650242505ab7530f531782bffd6b1
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 4ffd4a084cac545b680fd879a891f20db814bc4b74901e26fbe1676b5a29ade1
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 4658094e3d4aeadec4e1d70023c8b20970c98543a569c5c0e3edc4caee4277c5
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 46438c1226b4684f69512bc2829e32a4e2420ae2cb1e8ab516c3439f2988bcdc-init
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 1a618f110ebebf2423780b6ee030b1e357ce9f426f877f55a1606caa0bbc107e
drwx--x--x 1 nobody nogroup  78 Jul 26 13:25 02ba91d136afc3790be35ae35c5ad022b68377edc3963cf757e4e0b6da0d3414
```

Comment: Have you looked for containers [which have that volume mounted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42858081/530160)?

Comment: `I'd backed-up my Linux container, performed a power wash on the Chromebook, then restored the Linux container.` How did you restore the container? Did you copy files into `/var/lib/docker`?

Comment: Using the standard ChromeOS backup/restore mechanisms.  I've read it's basically a prettied-up `tar`.  Before uninstalling Docker I'd run `docker system prune` to try to clear everything out... since I had no useful images and wasn't running any containers... but those subvolumes persisted.

Comment: Did you use `--volumes`? prune doesn't remove volumes by default.

Comment: I hadn't... but did just now.  That cleaned up some of the _new_ volumes, but I still have those same 23 old subvolumes.

Comment: Very similar experience (even using a new Chromebook and restoring Linux beta).  'btrfs subvolume delete XXXXXX' was the only thing that worked for me to get rid of last volumes, which I assume were corrupted somehow. BTRFS has a lot of problems in Docker it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a similar problem, but this method solved it. What do you think?

```sh
$ btrfs subvolume delete /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes/*
$ apt remove docker-ce
$ rm -rf /var/lib/docker/
$ apt install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here. And my workaround is...

```
# systemctl stop docker
# mv /var/lib/docker/btrfs/subvolumes /var/lib/docker/btrfs/delme
# systemctl start docker
```

Files are still alive. But your Docker will work again.

Answer (score 0):

apt install thunar
then refer to the

> /var/lib/

and open terminal there then
write

> sudo thunar

and delete docker folder
and then reinstall docker from scratch it did work to me with manjaro