# Docker show relation between container and auto created volumes

Tags: docker

is it possible to show relations between container and volumes?
My problem is that my docker server has round about 44k volumes, most of them are dangling. and before I want to run a prune I want to know which of my container creates so much volumes.
cheers chris

Comment: This post might help you, you can check the attached volumes per container. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to look at the system events log for past day to see what is going on.

```
docker system events --since `date -d "1 day ago" +%s`
```

If the containers are not destroyed immediately or they run for a while, you can try to inspect the containers with:

```
docker container inspect <hash>
```

To see what images and volumes are being mapped.