# Docker - "Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/project/node_modules/.cache/@babel'"

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

Running `yarn docker-build` works fine but when `yarn docker-up` or `yarn docker-dev` an error pops up when `RUN yarn` is called. Nginx starts up fine but yarn fails into mkdir in the Projects directory.

package.json

```
...
    "docker-build": "docker-compose build",
    "docker-dev": "cross-env NGINX_HOST=localhost NGINX_PORT=3000 PORT=3000 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --no-deps",
    "docker-up": "cross-env NGINX_HOST=localhost NGINX_PORT=80 PORT=8080 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --no-deps -d",
    "docker-down": "docker-compose down"
...
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8

# Install required dependencies (Alpine Linux packages)
RUN apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache \
    sudo \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    git \
    libev-dev \
    libevent-dev \
    libuv-dev \
    make \
    openssl-dev \
    perl \
    python

# Add user and make it sudoer
ARG uid=1000
ARG user=username
RUN set -x ; \
  addgroup -g $uid -S $user ; \
  adduser -u $uid -D -S -G $user $user \
  && exit 0 ; exit 1
RUN echo $user' ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

# Install (global) Yarn packages/dependencies
RUN yarn global add node-gyp
RUN git clone --recursive https://github.com/sass/node-sass.git \
  && cd node-sass \
  && yarn \
  && node scripts/build -f

# Make project directory with permissions
RUN mkdir /project

# Switch to project directory
WORKDIR /project

# Copy required stuff
COPY . .

# Give owner rights to the current user
RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /project

# Install (local) Yarn packages and build
RUN yarn

USER $user
```

Error

```
app_1    | [2] Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/project/node_modules/.cache/@babel'
app_1    | [2]     at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
app_1    | [2]     at sync (/project/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
app_1    | [2]     at sync (/project/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
app_1    | [2]     at save (/project/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:50:20)
app_1    | [2]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
app_1    | [2]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
app_1    | [2]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
app_1    | [2]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
app_1    | [2]     at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

My repo can be found here at https://github.com/cozy-nyc/cozy-nyc

Comment: Where does username in `ARG user=username` come from?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with npm. I fixed it using:

```
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

The other way is to specify it in your install command:

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm thePackage
```

You can find the documentation for it here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

Comment: Has this been removed from later versions?

Answer (score 12):

Try setting the user before running `yarn` in your Dockerfile.

```
# Give owner rights to the current user
RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /project

USER $user

# Install (local) Yarn packages and build
RUN yarn
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably have a volume specified in your `docker-compose` file and mounted as `/project/node_modules`, your user does not have permission to access that directory on your local disk.

Find out which local directory the volume is mapped to using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers) and change the owner with:

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername /path/to/node_modules
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding volumes of `./node_modules` to you docker-compose file under your application service.

Something like:

```
services:
  app:
    command: yarn start
    volumes:
      - .:/project
      - ./node_modules:/project/node_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do like what was suggested here (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1262#issuecomment-677577653). So change the following lines from this

```
# Copy required stuff
COPY . .

# Give owner rights to the current user
RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /project
```

to this

```
# Copy required stuff
COPY --chown $user:$user . .
```

Or as alternative change your `WORKDIR` (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/740#issuecomment-458545074):

```
WORKDIR /home/node/project
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `COPY --chown=$USER:$USER . .`

Answer (score 0):

I had these kinds of errors and after a long time of trying I found out that Docker's (Mac OS X) Experimental Features were the reason.

I had checked both "Use the new Virtualization framework" and "Enable VirtioFS accelerated directory sharing"

After disabling them, npm works properly.