# Permission error on react docker project : EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Good evening I created a react project, with a docker file, and a docker-composes file but when the dockerfile build there is a permission error in the node_module foalder located in the container.

> _1  | Failed to compile.
> web_1  |
> web_1  | EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/node_modules/.cache'

[image]

Comment: I just started to learn docker and if I understood well the folder /app is in the container which is the instance of the image, I only have access to the app folder from the dockerfile.

Comment: See this: [Docker - “Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/project/node_modules/.cache/@babel'”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55926705/2873538)