# How to interpret /dev/vda1?

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile these were the contents,

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html/public
VOLUME src/ /var/www/html/public
EXPOSE 80
```

You see, I have mounted `/src` to `/var/www/html/public` now I went to the container to find out the what all mounts have been made inside the container more specifically finding out `/src /var/ww/html/public`.

I searched it and found the command `/proc/mounts` can help me out. So I tried, results are

```
...
/dev/vda1 /src ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vda1 /etc/resolv.conf ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vda1 /etc/hostname ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vda1 /etc/hosts ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/vda1 /var/www/html/public ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
...
```

This part of the results does contains things that I want to know. As very first line contains `/src` and the 5th line contains `/var/www/html/public` **But how do I interpret the results. In other words, by looking the file contents how do I know that host `/src` mounted to container directory `/var/www/html/public`?**

What I thought I would get the results like this.

`/src /var/www/html/public` but instead `/dev/vda1` was interfering, So How do I understand this.

Comment: `/dev/vda1` is a virtual disk refering to the real disk. I think you accidentially created another mount from `/src`.

Comment: hi @dan1st, I have highlighted the question more specifically. If possible please add more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30133664/10871900 explains how to test what is mounted to what.

Comment: But this can't be happen when you are inside the container, let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: No, the container does not know where the mounts go to. A computer does not know the physical location of hard drives, too. You could locate them outside of it and connect a cable.

Comment: I think found something, just want to share: This command: `mount | grep ^/dev/ | grep -v /etc | awk '{print $3}'` returns the host volumes.

In this way:

`/src 
/var/www/html/public
`

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile cannot declare any specific host directories.  Instead, what you've done is told Docker to create two *anonymous volumes* on the directories `./src` and `/var/www/html/public`.  There's almost no reason to do this, and you should just delete that `VOLUME` line.

Mounting a host directory over your application's source code isn't necessarily a best practice: it means you're not running the code built into the image, and so the image might not actually run reproducibly in a different environment.  If you need to, then you need a `docker run -v` option when you start the container.  There's nothing you need in the Dockerfile to make this possible, and you can't mandate it.

There's no easy way to tell what volumes are mounted from inside a container, and Docker by design hides details of the host system like this (hence multiple different things all apparently being mounted from the same device).  You can test the specific effect of editing a file in the host/container and seeing the corresponding change in the container/host.  A comment also cited [How do you list volumes in docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers) which lists out several ways to test this with `docker` commands, from the host.