# How to push files from docker Jenkins to local dir

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume

I am new to the Jenkins and docker. I wonder if there is way to push the files from container to local. I mounted local dir to docker, but it seems all files only updated in container.

local dir: /home/xyz/
container dir: /var/jenkins_home/xyz

```
docker run \
  --name jenkins \
  --restart=on-failure \
  --detach \
  --network jenkins \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client \
  --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/home/xyz/,target=/var/jenkins_home/xyz \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  myjenkins-blueocean:2.361.3-1
```

Answer (score 0):

- When you ran `Jenkins` image using `--volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home`  you used [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Docker manages the volume and you can find the exact data location by [inspecting the volumes of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers).
- When you used `--mount type=bind,source=/home/xyz/,target=/var/jenkins_home/xyz` you mapped the folder `/var/jenkins_home/xyz` from the container to folder `/home/xyz/` on the docker host using [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/). Jenkins home data changes in the container are reflected on the host path. Create a new job and you will see its definition in `jobs` folder.

You should use either docker volumes or bind mounts, not both for a single data folder.

- If you want to copy data from the container to the host use `docker cp` command.