# Is there a way how a docker container was run?

Tags: docker

When you want to run a (docker) container, you use `docker run` with additional parameters such as "-it" or mapping volumes etc.

Once you do that you can see the running containers with `docker ps`

My question is, assuming that I have no way of knowing how a container was run, but the container is currently running, is there a way to see how it was run?

I am specifically interested in see what volume mapping was used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133664/how-do-you-list-volumes-in-docker-containers