# can I mount a file from volume in docker to the container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I put one security file like `id_rsa` in the docker volume `larrycai_vol`, trying to mount this into the container as a file.

```
$ docker volume inspect larrycai-vol
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2018-05-18T06:02:24Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/larrycai-vol/_data",
        "Name": "larrycai-vol",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Do we have some command like below (it doesn't work now)

```
docker run -it -v larrycai-vol/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa own_ubuntu
```

I know it works if I mount file from docker host

```
docker run -it -v $PWD/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa own_ubuntu
```

Comment: IMO this should work for files as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137544/how-to-map-volume-paths-using-dockers-volumes-from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, let me a couple of considerations furthermore the proposed solution to avoid further misunderstandings.

- Docker allows mounting volumes (deployed from path dir of your host to docker path, i.e, `-v $PWD/.ssh:/root/.ssh` = *it'd replace complete .ssh folder in destination, so, it's not recommended although possible*)
- Docker allows mounting named volumes (deployed from named volume name to docker path, i.e, `-v larrycai-vol:/root/.ssh` = *it'd replace complete .ssh folder in destination, so, it's not recommended although possible*)
- Docker allows mounting files from host to a docker (example: `-v $PWD/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa` = **your second example**)
- Docker allows mounting files from named volume to a docker (example: `-v /var/lib/docker/volumes/YOUR_NAMED_VOLUME_NAME/_data/file:/dest_dir/file` = **what you're trying to do**)

Your mistake is that you're telling docker to mount id_rsa from your larrycai-vol directory, not from docker named volume. 
In other words, **three following commands are equivalent**:

```
docker run -it -v ./larrycai-vol/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa own_ubuntu
docker run -it -v $PWD/larrycai-vol/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa own_ubuntu
docker run -it -v larrycai-vol/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa own_ubuntu
```

So, if larrycai-vol directory (not named volume, but directory in your host) doesn't exist, command doesn't work as you want.

Definitively, to do what you're trying you have to create a `bind volume`to the directory where named volume store data.

> `docker run -it -v
>   /var/lib/docker/volumes/larrycai-vol/_data/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa
>   own_ubuntu`

Comment: solution 4 shall work, but looks ugly ;-), hope we can support extra file paramter in mount tag this `--mount source=<file>|<path>`

Comment: It hasn't already been provided by docker. I also hope in following versions it can be possible.

Comment: mounting a file from a named volume (4th bullet point) is certainly something that one should NOT do.